# Filter dataframe by two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `A`, contains hourly weather data for each city.

```
City  Hour  Temperature
A      1      30
A      2      32
...
B      1      39
B      2      40
```

I have another dataframe B, which indicates which record in `A` I am interested to analyze.

```
City  Hour  
A      1     
B      2
```

How can I filter `A` by `B`?

Expected output:

```
City  Hour  Temperature
A      1      30
B      2      40
```

Currently, I am using inner join.

Comment: Pandas document as an excellent answer : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge`

```
df.merge(dfb)
Out[820]: 
  City  Hour  Temperature
0    A     1           30
1    B     2           40
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not as straightforward as @Wen's `merge`, you can do:

```
A.set_index(['City','Hour']).loc[pd.Index(B)].reset_index()

  City  Hour  Temperature
0    A     1           30
1    B     2           40
```